# Can't validate contact form with JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

This is my very first attempt at building a website. I need to validate my contact form (no plugins) with JQuery. I tried following a few tutorials but nothing I try works. What am I doing wrong? :(

http://jsfiddle.net/LnQ9C/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactform").validate({
        rule: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: "true",
                email: true
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please enter your name",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form){
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Also, how can I make it so the form emails me the details?

Comment: FYI, there is no such thing as the `.validate()` method in jQuery.  As used in your code above, `.validate()` is part of the [jQuery Validate **PLUGIN**](http://jqueryvalidation.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> "*I need to validate my contact form (**no plugins**) with jQuery.  I tried following a few tutorials but nothing I try works. What am I doing wrong?"*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contactform").validate({
        rule: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: "true",
                email: true
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please enter your name",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            submitHandler: function(form){
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**There are quite a few syntax problems here, but most importantly, the code you're trying to make work depends on a plugin!**  The `.validate()` method used in this context is part of [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org), which [you've not included in the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnQ9C/).

**BTW, There is no such thing as a `.validate()` method in jQuery without using a plugin.**

---

Here are the problems...

1)  You must include the jQuery Validate plugin or the `.validate()` method means nothing to jQuery.

2) Your submit button needs to be a `type="submit"` and does not need any inline JavaScript `onclick` handlers.  Change this...

```
<input type="button" onclick="validate_form();" />
```

into this...

```
<input type="submit" />
```

3)  The `rules` option is spelled `rules` and not `rule`.

4)  The `messages` and `submitHandler` options do not belong inside of `rules`.  They are siblings or `rules`, not children.

5)  For your `required` rule under `email`, the `true` value does not belong within quotation marks.

6)  You will not need to include the `submitHandler` callback as long as it only contains `form.submit()`, because that is the default behavior.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contactform").validate({  // <-- requires jQuery Validate plugin
        rules: {                  // <-- spelled "rules" with an "s"
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,   // <-- true does not need quotation marks
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {               // <-- this option is a sibling of 'rules'
            name: "Please enter your name",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        }
    });
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/g6P7c/**

---

[See my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721795/594235) for how to do jQuery Validation without a plugin.

Comment: Ah thank you :) I had already added the plugin to the actual code so it was the syntax errors that was still causing me trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for this. Or even JavaScript.

```
<input type="text" name="name" required title="Please enter your name" />
<input type="email" name="email" required title="Please enter a valid email address" />
```

Done. This is the magic of HTML5.

Comment: I'll be sure to take note of that for future reference but this is a project for class and one of the requirements is using jquery/javascript to validate the form.

Comment: Personally, if I were teaching that class, I'd give you bonus points for being awesome if you used this HTML5 ;)

Comment: FYI - check for HTML5 browser compatibility.  http://fmbip.com/litmus/ or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML_5%29

Answer (score 1):

First replace:

```
<input type="button" onclick="validate_form();" />
```

to:

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

You don't need use button and listen "onclick", and put right options for jquery.validate:

```
$("#contactform").validate({
    rules: { // "rules" not "rule"
     name: "required",
     email: {
      required: true, // boolean type, "true" is a string
      email: true
     }
    }, // message is new property
    messages: {
      name: "Please enter your name",
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
      form.submit();
    }
 }
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/LnQ9C/2/

Comment: It still submits the form regardless of whether it's filled in correctly or not.

Comment: likely u have other javascript error. For use jquery.validate u need include library(http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js) into <head> tag

Comment: for debugging javascript use Google chorme https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging.

Comment: @lastbyte All major browsers are capable of debugging JS. Yes, even IE!

Comment: The debugger keeps sending me to the 1.6.2 library and saying "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." What does that mean and what does it have to do with my form?

Comment: this is notice, not error. function for event click, mousemove, etc. using return false or true. Right using event.preventDefault(); but returnValue working too

Comment: jQuery plugin validate Required
jQuery, tested with 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.0, can u change jQuery verison?

Answer (score 0):

**Quote OP:**

> "*I need to validate my contact form (**no plugins**) with jQuery.  I tried following a few tutorials but nothing I try works. What am I doing wrong?"*

[See my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20721229/594235) for a detailed explanation of the syntax problems in your original code.  **The code you're trying to make work depends on a plugin!**  The `.validate()` method used in this context is part of [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org), which [you've not included in the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LnQ9C/).

**BTW, There is no such thing as a `.validate()` method in jQuery without using a plugin.**

However, without a plugin, and without doing all of your homework for you, here is a very crude demo of something like you'll need to do.  It only validates one field as `required` and does not give specific error messages. However, from this point, you should be able to expand it easily.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#button").on('click', function (e) {  // <- capture the button click

        e.preventDefault();                  // <- block the form submit

        // test your form's validity

        if ($('#name').val() == '') {        // <- make name field required
            alert('form not valid');         // <- form not valid - somehow alert user
        } else {            
            $('#contactform').submit();      // <- form is valid - submit it
        }

    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Z2RGa/**